# can't skin DateSpinner

Tags: apache-flex

I have the following mxml file in an Adobe AIR Desktop app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
xmlns:dns="flash.net.dns.*">

 <fx:Declarations>   
 </fx:Declarations>

 <fx:Script>    
 </fx:Script>

 <s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="center" />
 </s:layout>

 <s:DateSpinner id="ds"
               selectedDate="{new Date(2010, 11, 15)}"
               minDate="{new Date(2000, 0, 1)}"
               maxDate="{new Date(2200, 11, 31)}"
               minuteStepSize="5" />

 <!-- toggle between different display modes -->
 <s:HGroup>
    <s:Button label="Date" 
              click="ds.displayMode = DateSelectorDisplayMode.DATE" />
    <s:Button label="Time" 
              click="ds.displayMode = DateSelectorDisplayMode.TIME" />
    <s:Button label="Date and Time" 
              click="ds.displayMode = DateSelectorDisplayMode.DATE_AND_TIME" />
 </s:HGroup>

</s:Application>
```

When I run it in adl, I get the following messages:

Error: 
Skin for Flex_AIR_Test.ApplicationSkin2._ApplicationSkin_Group1.contentGroup.ds cannot be found.

Error: 
Skin for Flex_AIR_Test.ApplicationSkin2._ApplicationSkin_Group1.contentGroup.ds cannot be found.

DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x179cc0, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x17a5e0
DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x181190, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x1800b0

How do I include the defualt skin for DateSpinner?  I have the following swc's included in my project in FDT:

```
mobile.swc [frameworks/themes/Mobile/mobile.swc]
airglobal.swc [frameworks/libs/air/airglobal.swc]
framework.swc [frameworks/libs/framework.swc]
spark.swc [frameworks/libs/spark.swc]
mobilecomponents.swc [frameworks/libs/mobile/mobilecomponents.swc]
```

Do I need to include them in a particular order or enable the "Use as Runtime Shared Code" checkbox?

Mark

Comment: The DateSpinner is a mobile only component, if memory serves me.  I think you need to add the mobile theme to your project. It appears you are already doing that. Maybe you have to specify that the SWC is a theme using the theme compiler argument, like this? -theme="C:\flexSDK\frameworks\themes\Mobile\mobile.swc" You can specify two themes using the compiler argument; but it may cause other issues because now your app components will 'guess' which theme is appropriate.

Comment: specifying the -theme flag on the command line did the trick.

how do I mark www.Flextras.com's comment as the answer?

Comment: I'll post it as a formal answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DateSpinner is a mobile only component.

You'll have to specify the mobile theme SWC as a compiler argument, like this?

```
-theme="C:\flexSDK\frameworks\themes\Mobile\mobile.swc
```

You can specify two themes using the compiler argument; but it may cause other issues because now your app components will 'guess' which theme is appropriate.